# How to add new term from TaxonomyWebTaggingControl in custom code

Tags: taxonomy

How to add new term from TaxonomyWebTaggingControl in custom code

I have created a custom code which renders TaxonomyWebTaggingControl in the run time & i have binded the Taxonomy SSPID & TermSetID

My Question is how to Add new term in the TaxonomyWebTaggingControl which throws invalid term on postback.

Please me know how to add new term in TaxonomyWebTaggingControl

Thanks in Advance
Santhosh